# Apply function on Document Write and display it on textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to apply the function to display the result in a textarea using javascript. I have the following code, so far it writes the function on the body by using document.write, but i want to use the onclick button to display it on text area, how can I achieve this?

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>

    <script>
    function randomAlphanumeric() {
        var str = '',
                possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
                numberOfLetters = 10;

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++) {
            str += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        return str;
    }

    document.write(randomAlphanumeric());
    </script>

    <style>
    body {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<button id="btn" onclick="randomAlphanumeric();"> test </button>

<textarea id="results" rows="10" cols="20"> </textarea>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write()` will write your function's return value to the entire document, overwriting any other elements and removing the textarea.

You can use `document.querySelector('textarea')` or `document.getElementById('results')` to specifically target your textarea, store that in a variable, and then use `yourVarName.value = randomAlphanumeric()` to change the value of the textarea to your desired text.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wntitus/52e3pf79/

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. By using `document.write` you are adding the string to the document body and not to the textarea. Use `document.getElementById( "results" ).value = str` instead to set your textarea value to the string.
2. You are writing the string outside your function, meaning it will always be displayed whether or not you click the button. Move the `document.getElementById( "results" ).value = str` line inside the function, at its end. If you do this you shouldn't need the `return str` statement.

```
<script>
function randomAlphanumeric() {
    var str = '',
    possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
    numberOfLetters = 10;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++) {
        str += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    document.getElementById( "results" ).value = str
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the results to innerHTML of the textarea on button click, see following codepen

https://codepen.io/parallaxisjones-the-typescripter/pen/MqNYxM?editors=1111

```
    function randomAlphanumeric() {
    var str = '',
            possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
            numberOfLetters = 10;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++) {
        str += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }

    return str;
}

document.write(randomAlphanumeric());

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e){
  document.getElementById('results').innerText = randomAlphanumeric();
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! This is exactly what I need, thank you parallaxis!

Answer (score 0):

The `document.write()` method overrides the page's content. In order to get your task done, you'll need to add a *click* event listener to the `button#btn`, that executes the `randomAlphanumeric` function, that will no longer return anything, it will just place the generated string in the `textarea#results` element.

Here's a demo snippet:

> Using inline event listeners isn't a wise choice, it's better to use the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

```js
// referencing the 'button' and the 'textarea' so we can use them later.
var btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
  textarea = document.getElementById('results');

// attaching a 'click' event listener to the 'button'. 
btn.addEventListener('click', randomAlphanumeric);

function randomAlphanumeric() {
  var str = '',
possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
numberOfLetters = 10;
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++) {
str += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  // place the generated string into the 'textarea'.
  results.value = str;
}
```

```css
#btn, #results {
  display: block;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Generate a random string</button>
<textarea placeholder="click the button to generate a string..." id="results"></textarea>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score -1):

You can just add your result to the innerHTML of the textarea:

```js
function randomAlphanumeric() {
  var str = '',
    possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
    numberOfLetters = 10;

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++) {
    str += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = str;
  // return str;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title></title>

<head>


  <style>
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="btn" onclick="randomAlphanumeric();"> test </button>

  <textarea id="results" rows="10" cols="20"> </textarea>



</body>

</html>
```